# Plural of "Average" as a noun?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I have a sentence lingering in my mind that I read somewhere, but the way I'm remembering it it doesn't sound right:

```
The averages have the power of invisibility.
```

Is this correct pluralization of 'average' as a noun?

Comment: ... that is a common trap when measuring changes, but averages is correct in that context!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have one average (of many scores, or of temperatures), then you use the word *average* in the singular.  If you have more than one average (average temperature, average rainfall, average barometric pressure, e.g.), then you could refer to that set of numbers as a set of *averages*.

There's nothing wrong with the sentence in your question.  You could remove the first word, too, if you wanted to refer to averages in general:

> Averages have the power of invisibility.

Answer (score 1):

While *average* is a general term referring to a central trend, there are several different types, such as *mean*, *median* and *mode*, and, like *averages* they all take conventional plurals: *means*, *medians*, *modes*.